# Periodic orbits of the logistic map

Tags: dynamical-systems, chaos-theory, bifurcation

I have a question about the period orbits of the logistic map $f(x)=r \cdot x(1-x), r \in [0,4], x \in [0,1]$.
The bifurcation-diagram own for $r<3.5699$ only periodic orbits of period $ p=2^k,k \in \mathbb{N}$. These period-doubling is a result of pitchfork-bifurcations. So far so clear. My question is about the periodic orbits of odd periods e.g. $5,7,9,11,...$

The periodic orbit of period $3$ arises through a saddle-node bifurcation. That is, when a pair of fixed points collapse and leave behind a single fixed point of higher period. In the paper "The logistic map and the birth of Period-3 Cycle" by Alberto, Ariel, and Yu.A. $(2012)$ one can see the birth of the periodic orbit of period $3$ through a tangent bifurcation at $r = 1 + 2 \sqrt2$.

So far so good. But I have tho following questions:

$1$: Why can't we see in the following bifurcation-diagram of the logistic map [[image: Birth of a period <span class=]$3$ orbit." />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKdE2.jpg) that for $r$ just a little bit smaller than $1 + 2 \sqrt2$ that we have a declining number of periodic points but the birth of the period $3$ orbit is abruptly? Because for $r<1+2 \sqrt2$ we have many periodic points and I thought that a saddle-node bifurcation only reduces the number of fixed points by half. So how is it possible, that all of the sudden we have an orbit of period $3$?

$2$: Are the stable periodic orbits of period $5,7,9,11,...$ formed analogous to the orbit of period $3$? And is there any result that proofs the existence of periodic orbits for any odd number?

Comment: The 3-cycle already exists before, it is just that at this point it becomes stable. For smaller $r$ there are no stable cycles of small or moderate periods, or any at all, so you get densely filled (at least visually) segments.

Comment: How can one proof, that the $3$-cycle existed before? Or isn't this question that important?

How can one proof, that the chain $(x, f(x), f^2(x), x, f(x), f^2(x),...)$ existed before?

Comment: A 3-cycle (almost) always exists, its points are the solutions of a polynomial $(f_r^3(z)-z)/(f_r(z)-z)=0$ of degree 6. You have values of $r$ where these solutions are complex, where they are real but the cycle is unstable and where they are real and the cycle is stable. The cycle is visible only in the latter case. Note that in consequence of Sharkovskii, if the 3 cycle is real, then also all the other cycles exist, but will in general be unstable.

Comment: The polynomial is $r^6 z^6 - ( 3 r^6 + r^5) z^5 + (3 r^6 + 4 r^5 + r^4) z^4 - ( r^6 + 5 r^5 + 3 r^4 + r^3) z^3 + (2 r^5 + 3 r^4 + 3 r^3 + r^2) z^2 - ( r^4 + 2 r^3 + 2 r^2 + 
    r) z + r^2 + r + 1=0$.

Answer (score 1):

I refer you to the theorem by [Sharkovskii](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharkovskii%27s_theorem), which gives a certain order relation for periodic orbits. This is related to the famous result by Li and Yorke, known as 'period 3 implies chaos'.

Basically - once you have period $3$, you have periods of all lengths. More generally, Sharkovskii's theorem gives you a characterization of which periodic orbits you may have, based on the existence of a "maximal" orbit in the order relation. The orbits located lowest in the order relation are the powers of two, which can be seen from the bifurcation diagram. The periodic orbits of odd order are highest in the order relation, and if you have a periodic orbit of odd order, then you will have orbits of all even orders.

Comment: I think that Sharkovskii`s theorem isn't useful here. Sharkovskii`s theorem tells you that if you have an periodic orbit of period three, you'll find for any period a starting point with the certain period. Yes in this case e.g. $r=3.83$ I have an stable orbit of period $3$ and unstable orbits of all periods, but Sharkovskii`s theorem doesn't tells us something about the existente of period orbits of period $5,7,9,...$. The bifurcation-diagramm shows us the stable periodic orbits of period $5,7,9,...$ but does all periods even exist in an stable periodic orbit, so we can see it in the diagram?

Comment: @David So maybe I did not understand exactly what your are asking about. You are asking specifically how one can see that these periodic orbits of odd order (whose existence is guaranteed by Sharkovskii) are stable?

Comment: yes that my point. So my first question was answered. But I still don't see or I still don't know, how one can argue, that there are stable orbits of all periods (specifically odd numbers) in the bifurcation-diagram of the logistic map. Or does the logistic map has a period $3$ orbit for all values of $r$ but this period $3$ orbits is stable just for certain values of $r$? So the logistic map has for all values period orbits of all periods by Sharkovskii but sometimes e.g. in the period $3$ window just the orbit of period $3$ is stable?